# grails xml unmarshalling

Tags: grails, xml-parsing, grails-2.0

Since Grails 1.1.x, they have supported XML and JSON unmarshalling for REST requests. I can't seem to get this working in version 2.1.0. Here is the relevant files from the example project I am using to test the functionality:

1. UrlMappings.groovy

   ```
   static mappings = {
       "/$action/$id?"(controller:'verification',parseRequest:true)

       "/"(view:"/index")
       "500"(view:'/error')
   }
   ```
2. Tester.groovy

   ```
   class Tester {
       String name
       String vendor

       String toString() {
           return "$name $vendor"
       }
   }
   ```
3. VerificationController.groovy

   ```
   class VerificationController {

       def save() {
           Tester tester = new Tester(params.tester)
           log.error "Tester = ${tester}"
           log.error "Request XML = ${request.XML}"
       }
   }
   ```
4. XML send with REST call

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <tester>
       <name>Windows</name>
       <vendor>Microsoft</vendor>
   </tester>
   ```

When I pass the XML in, the controller log statements output this:

```
Tester = null null
Request XML = WindowsMicrosoft
```

My bewilderment would be in why it recognizes it as XML (by putting it in the XML field of the request) but won't parse it and put it in params as defined [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#REST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for a few hours with the same problem I found a solution for me.

My problem was that I didn't had a content-type defined in my REST call.

So if you add `content-type: application/xml` to your rest call it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with almost exactly the same setup.  I believe your problem could lie within the UrlMapping configuration.  Initially I had the following.

```
"/rest/airport/$iata?"(controller: "airport", action: "restHandler", parseRequest: "true")
```

When I PUT/POST XML to that URI, it would show up correctly in request.XML, but it would never show up in the params object.  I then realized I had the parseRequest boolean in quotes.  Removing that fixed the issue.

```
"/rest/airport/$iata?"(controller: "airport", action: "restHandler", parseRequest: true)
```

Now, if your code is truly the same as what you have above, your problem may not be exactly the same.  However, what might help is making some kind of change to your UrlMappings to see if you could get it working a different way.

At first I thought it might have been the single quotes you had, but that seemed to work fine either way I tried it.  So, I would suggest just changing your URI mapping to something else and be very picky about the formatting.  In the end it was just a minor formatting issue in the UrlMappings.groovy file that fixed my problem.